# Please help. ADODB.Field error '800a0bcd' Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. line 154 in my ASP code

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic, eof, jscript, recordset

Can anyone please help me resolve this problem? My code has recordset (Question), as in below. Line 154 also shown. But I get ADODB.Field error '800a0bcd'. Many thanks

```
 <%
 var Question__MMColParam = "1";
 if (String(Request.QueryString("ID")) != "undefined" && 
 String(Request.QueryString("ID")) != "") { 
 Question__MMColParam = String(Request.QueryString("ID"));
 }
 %>

 <%
 var Question = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset");
 Question.ActiveConnection = MM_Recipe_STRING;
 Question.Source = "SELECT * FROM SurveyQuestions WHERE QuestionID = 
 "+ Question__MMColParam.replace(/'/g, "''") + "";
 Question.CursorType = 0;
 Question.CursorLocation = 2;
 Question.LockType = 1;
 Question.Open();
 var Question_numRows = 0;
 %>
```

```
This is Lines 153 to 158
```

```
 <%
 var Survey__IDParam = "0";
 if (String(Question.Fields("QuestionSurvey")) != "undefined" && 
     String(Question.Fields("QuestionSurvey")) != "")
   { 
     Survey__IDParam = String(Question.Fields("QuestionSurvey"));
   }
 %>
```

Comment: I would guess your query isn't finding any matching records.  What data type is the QuestionID field?  It looks like it would have to be a number since you aren't putting single quotes around it in the query.

Comment: He said the error type was "ADODB.Field error '800a0bcd", if it didn't find a record it would be an End Of File type error though right?  There is probably an issue with datatypes if I was to guess.  You are searching for a STRING but aren't the ID's Integers and thus numbers?

Comment: You need to check if the recordset is not at eof  before accessing it. Enclose line 154 to 158 within an if check. `if(!Question.eof){....}`

Comment: Also do a `Response.Write(Question.Source);` and see what the actual query is

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. I'll work on them and post success or otherwise. @niidod

Comment: @easleyfixed that is the `800a0bcd` error - "Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted". It means the `ADODB.Recordset` is empty, they need to debug the query and test it in MS Access first.

Comment: Ahh yes that is the EoF/BoF error number, my bad.  But did the other part I mentioned about trying to compare a string to an integer fix help with trying to fix the problem?

Comment: @easleyfixed Yes, the IDs are integers. I was of the impression a sort of 'parse' is achieved with .replace() method in the code. (Question.Source = "SELECT * FROM SurveyQuestions WHERE QuestionID = "+ Question__MMColParam.replace(/'/g, "''") + "";). My ASP knowledge limited though. Thanks

Comment: I also did if(!Question.eof){....} as suggested by @flakes. The page displayed in browser after that. But just the HTML/CSS. ASP code threw another error: ADODB.Field error '800a0e78'

Operation is not allowed when the object is closed. I'll post this in another question + complete code. Thank you all.